# Error Creating Simple Countdown to Date App in Swift 4

Tags: swift

So, I am currently working on an app that will do a simple countdown to a specific date; however, I am getting this error: "Value of type '(NSCalendar.Unit, Date, Date [NSCalendar.Options]) -> ()' has no member 'day' "

Any way to fix this to finish the app?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var CountdownText: UILabel!
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    let userCalendar = NSCalendar.current

    let requestedComponent: NSCalendar.Unit = [
        NSCalendar.Unit.month,
        NSCalendar.Unit.day,
        NSCalendar.Unit.hour,
        NSCalendar.Unit.minute,
        NSCalendar.Unit.second,
    ]

    func printTime()
    {
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
        let startTime = NSDate()
        let endTime = formatter.date(from: "12/03/18 2:00:00 p")

        func timeDifference (requestedComponent: NSCalendar.Unit, from: Date, to: Date, options: [NSCalendar.Options]) {}

        CountdownText.text = "\(timeDifference.day) Days \(timeDifference.minute) Minutes \(timeDifference.second) Seconds"
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in `func timeDifference`, so it's considered as `Void`, and type `Void` does not have members `day`, `minute`, or `second`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get call `.day` property from your `function` type which does and returns nothing.
I bet your function `timeDifference` should be somewhere outside the `printTime` function.
Believe you want to do something like following:

```
func printTime() {
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    let startTime = Date()
    let endTime = formatter.date(from: "12/03/18 2:00:00 p")

    let days = timeDifference(requestedComponent: .day, from: startTime, to: endTime, options: [])
    let minutes = timeDifference(requestedComponent: .minute, from: startTime, to: endTime, options: [])
    let seconds = timeDifference(requestedComponent: .second, from: startTime, to: endTime, options: [])
    CountdownText.text = "\(days) Days \(minutes) Minutes \(seconds) Seconds"
}

func timeDifference (requestedComponent: NSCalendar.Unit, from: Date, to: Date, options: [NSCalendar.Options]) -> Int {
    var calculatedValue = 0
    // calculatings
    return calculatedValue
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Your method removed all of the errors for me; however, when I try to run the program itself, the label's text remains the same and stays as 'Label.' How can i fix this?

Comment: @WilliamSail if you have an outlet to your label (or any reference to it) you have to write like `myLabel.text = "whatever your text is"`. I can't clearly say what you need to do because I don't know what `CountdownText` is.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a function named timeDifference() and you're trying to access it like a variable instance

Here's what you need to do:-

```
 func timeDifference (requestedComponent: NSCalendar.Unit, from: Date, to: Date, options: [NSCalendar.Options]) {
     //Do your things here
 }
```

And call the function inside the variable this way:-

```
 var text = "\(timeDifference(requestedComponent: .day, from: Date(), to: Date(), options: [.searchBackwards])) Days \(timeDifference(requestedComponent: .minute, from: Date(), to: Date(), options: [.searchBackwards])) Minutes \(timeDifference(requestedComponent: .second, from: Date(), to: Date(), options: [.searchBackwards])) Seconds"
```

Additionally, you can make your function parameters optional like this:-

```
 func timeDifference (requestedComponent: NSCalendar.Unit, from: Date, to: Date, options: [NSCalendar.Options]? = nil) {}
```

The fourth parameter here is optional and the you don't have to provide an option every time. It's considered to be nil without input and it won't affect you in any way, unless you use it somewhere within the function, where you might have to handle it with an 'if' statement
(Just in case if it helps!)

NOTE:-

You can also return a "NSCalendar.Unit" from your function and use it for calculation, in which case, your usage pattern is right.

But I assume that the function here is written for the purpose of calculation and you're dealing with a label's value to display the calculated result. Dealing this all within a function is the sole purpose of a function, and hence I recommend doing this

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use function (with no return type) as NSCalendarComponent, hence it is showing you error. Instead, you and get start time and end time components like this:

```
func printTime(){
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startTime=calendar.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: Date())
    print("\(startTime.hour!):\(startTime.minute!):\(startTime.second!)")

    let endTime = calendar.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: formatter.date(from: "12/03/18 2:00:00 p") ?? Date())
    print("\(endTime.hour!):\(endTime.minute!):\(endTime.second!)")

   //do calculations here for time difference
}
```

and now you can calculate time difference and show it on countdown text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `NSCalendar` and `NSDate` at all in Swift 3+.

Your code doesn't work because the function `timeDifference` has no return value and does nothing anyway.

You probably mean

```
let requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]

...

func timeDifference (requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component>, from: Date, to: Date) -> DateComponents {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: from, to: to)
}

... 

let difference = timeDifference(requestedComponents: requestedComponents, from: startTime, to: endTime)
CountdownText.text = "\(difference.day!) Days \(difference.minute!) Minutes \(difference.second!) Seconds"
```

---

There is a more convenient way to calculate and display time differences, [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter)

```
func printTime()
{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    let startTime = Date()
    let endTime = formatter.date(from: "12/03/18 2:00:00 p")!
    let componentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    componentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    componentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
    CountdownText.text = componentsFormatter.string(from: startTime, to: endTime)
}
```

Comment: This was a fix for my issue! Thanks a lot! However, When I run the application, the CountdownText label still displays just 'Label.' Why is it not updating in runtime?

Comment: You have to call `printTime()` whenever the timer fires. I assume that there is a `Timer` instance.

Comment: Where would the timer instance be located?

Comment: In the view controller. It's the actual *countdown engine*.